# Python pandas dataframe: get tuple via dataframe max

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following pandas Dataframe `df`:

[image]

How could I get back a tuple (**Date**, **max(Close)**) using the `df.max` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), like this:

```
print(df.Close.idxmax(), df.Close.max()) # returns a tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
date = df['Close'].argmax()   # Returns the date with max(Close)
(date, df.loc[date, 'Close']) # The tuple you want
```

Comment: Try not to perform chain-indexing in general in pandas. You can obtain the value with 1 call to `__getattr__` through `.loc` via: df.loc[date, 'Close']` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: @CameronRiddell Thanks for the tip! Updated my answer.